# Standard Library Reference for Ruby

Tags: ruby, reference

I need a good reference for how to use standard Libraries in Ruby. Current libraries do not describe or give examples like say Java's. Yet this is where examples are much more needed (in Ruby), because I am not familiar with what the called method will yield! I am left with having to look at the source files every time, which seems inefficient. What is a good standard library reference... or am I just not understanding blocks yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [Ruby Standard Library documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/) and sites like [apidock](http://apidock.com/ruby/browse). [The Pickaxe book](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0) has a great reference towards the end. There's even [a free version online](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/), but it's quite out of date; to find the reference there, click [Standard Library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/lib_standard.html) in the top-left frame.

Comment: +1 for apidock, there guide is done very well, includes both core and standard so I don't have to guess (nuby here). I'll use this for now, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I find myself bouncing around between the ruby core API on [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org), googling for answers on random blogs, and spending time testing ideas in the interactive interpreter (irb). I haven't seen any other core reference documentation that I liked, but I do have a copy of [The Ruby Way](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d.html/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/178-3758195-6389929?a=0672328844) and its pretty decent.

Betweeen these four sources I can almost always find out how to solve the problem I'm working on.

Best of luck - ruby is fun, frustrating, and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Try [GotAPI](http://www.gotapi.com) You'll be able to find the Ruby standard documentation and a whole lot of api docs there

Answer (score 0):

Understanding blocks is pretty important, especially if you want to understand the `Enumerable` module. ruby-doc.org is usually all I need, but if I need a little more explanation I grab the [PickAxe](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9). You *need* the PickAxe, no question.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry , but again, i have to recommend [ruby cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0028N4WL0). (Already two times today)